# Question about locking strategy (C# / .NET 3.5 SP1)

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-3.5

I need to write a class that hold as Dictionary. The Dictionary will be accessed by multiple threads.
Each access will be very short.

I expect:

- every minute an access that adds or removes entries
- Every 2 sec. I need to create a copy of that dict. to run checks over it (and then e.g. call the DB)
- Multiple times per second I'm updated a field of the value to one of the keys. (value is a struct) The same key will not be accessed concurrently.

Which locking strategy would you choose and why?
My first shot is to use ReaderWriterLockSlim. But after I read it's a least two times slower than Monitor, I'm not so sure anymore, as everytime I access the dict, I'm going to lock very short.

tia
Martin

Comment: .NET 4.0 has the ConcurrentDictionary class that is thread safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the most frequent operation is *writing* and you never need multiple concurrent *readers* as far as I can see, I would just use a normal lock. I can't see that `ReaderWriterLockSlim` would help you, and it will certainly give you more complex code.

EDIT: One possible optimization is to just access a list of changes from the writing threads. The reading thread would then need to lock that list *just* while it updates the underlying dictionary before processing it. Assuming the dictionary is very large but the list of changes is relatively small, that means the writing threads will be blocked for a lot less time.

In fact, you could use something like `Queue` instead of a list, and potentially make the reading thread dequeue small batches and yield, reducing the latency of the writing threads even further - so if there were 100 changes to process, the reading thread might read 10 of them, yield so that any writing threads blocked waiting to add to the queue could get their turn.

There are ever more complex solutions to this, depending on how critical the performance is, particularly in terms of latency - but I'd start off with just a lock round the dictionary.

Comment: But given that he will need to copy (=read) from the dictionary every 2 seconds, wouldn't a simple lock have a bigger overhead?

Comment: @sternr: Why? The locking itself is cheap - it's the copying which will be slow, and you can't avoid that. You won't be able to do any writing while you're copying whichever locking strategy you use.

Comment: @sternr: AFAIK `lock` is faster than `ReaderWriterLockSlim`

Comment: Sorry obviously my description was not detailed enought. The access which will happen multiple times per second will never affect the same key concurrently. I'm a bit concerned that locking always the whole dictionary just to update a timestamp in value struct, will create a lock convoy.